# Difference between dates erroneously calculating getHours?

Tags: javascript

I am writing a function that will help me log elapsed times between my code blocks.

```js
function getTimestamp(date) {

    let hours = date.getHours();
    let minutes = date.getMinutes();
    let seconds = date.getSeconds();

    return `${(hours < 10 ? '0' + hours : hours)}-${(minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes)}-${(seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds)}`;
        
}

//example (wait 3 secs to see the output)
(async function(){
  let d1 = new Date();
  let seconds = 3;
  let interval = setInterval(function(){
     //console.clear();
     console.log(`wait ${seconds--} seconds...`); 
  }, 1000);
  let waitPromise = new Promise((ok,err) => {
    setTimeout(function(){
      ok(new Date());
    }, seconds * 1000);
  });
  let d2 = await waitPromise;
  //console.clear();
  clearInterval(interval);
  console.log(`Elapsed time: ${getTimestamp(new Date(d2 - d1))}`)
})();
```

I don't understand why my date differences are always showing 2 hours. The seconds and minutes are showing correctly, but I get a constant "2" hours together. Why is that happening ?

Comment: You are using absolute dates for time intervals. *Never* do that! You get 2 hours because the date is around midnight 1/1/1970 UTC and your timezone is UTC+2.

Comment: @D.Pardal: ugh... bingo. You (I...) never learn until you fall (I am sure I read about that at javascript.info). First time messing with dates in js...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, *never* use `Date` for time intervals. It will cause problems. Second, you should use `performance.now()` because it's meant for performance analysis and provides extra precision.

```js
function getHumanReadableTime(t) {
  const hours = Math.floor(t / 3600000),
  minutes = Math.floor(t / 60000) % 60,
  seconds = Math.floor(t / 1000) % 60;
  
  return `${hours}-${minutes}-${seconds}`
}

(async () => {
  const initialTimestamp = performance.now();
  await new Promise( ok => {setTimeout(ok, 3000)});
  const finalTimestamp = performance.now();
  alert(getHumanReadableTime(finalTimestamp - initialTimestamp));
})()
```